# HTML link playing audio before linking to next page

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am creating a program for a friend in a wheelchair who is non-verbal and can only move his head, a bit. I need a link to play an audio file before delivering to the next page.

```
<head>
<script>
function play() {
document.getElementById('test').play();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id='test' src='howdoyoufeel.wav'></audio>
<a href="activity.html">
<img src="smile.png" onClick='play()' />
</a>
</body>
```

Hello would be very much appreciated, trying to help him communicate!!

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this to first slightly change your HTML to give your link an ID, then target that ID with JavaScript in a setTimeout:

**HTML**

```
<a id="thelink" href="activity.html">
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function play() {
  document.getElementById('test').play();
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.getElementById('thelink').click();
  }, 3000); /* 3000 here is 3 seconds -- this should match the length of your audio */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You for your help.

Comment: No problem :) If this answer solved the problem for you, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)

Comment: Lack of points keeps public from seeing my vote. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but to Add to Obsidian's answer, you will need to move the img with the play() function call outside the anchor tag... otherwise the link will be fired off immediately.

So your HTML would look like this:

```
<a id="thelink" href="activity.html"></a>
<img src="smile.png" onClick='play()' />
```

Comment: Thank You for your help!

Comment: Your welcome :)

Please be sure to upvote Obsidians answer, since he answered it, I would have simply added my message as a comment, but I need more reputation before I'm allowed to do that, and felt like this piece of clarification was needed.